# Changed PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to FALSE and getting "Invalid parameter number" error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have the following code forexample:

```
$dbStatement=$this->dbObject->prepare("SELECT AVG(quality) as quality,
                                              AVG(adequacy) as adequacy,
                                              AVG(friendliness) as friendliness,
                                              SUM(overall) as overall,
                                              SUM(completed) as completed,
                                              type
                                       FROM   (SELECT AVG(quality) as quality,
                                                      AVG(adequacy) as adequacy,
                                                      AVG(friendliness) as friendliness,
                                                      COUNT(id) as overall,
                                                      SUM(is_completed) as completed,
                                                      category_id, type
                                               FROM valuation a
                                               WHERE status       =1
                                                 AND type         =:01
                                                 AND ((type='employer' AND owner_id=:02)
                                                      OR (type='employee' AND winner_id=:02))
                                               GROUP BY category_id
                                               HAVING COUNT(id)<=:03) b
                                       GROUP BY type");
$dbStatement->bindParam(':01',$Type);
$dbStatement->bindParam(':02',$UserID);
$dbStatement->bindParam(':03',$Most);
$dbStatement->execute();
```

This code throws an exception from `execute()` when I set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `FALSE`. The following message is included in the exception object:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Couldn't realize the problem so far, though read the corresponding manuals.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is due to **repetition of a placeholder**. Each placeholder must be unique, even if you are binding the same parameter to it.

```
AND ((type='employer' AND owner_id=:02)
OR (type='employee' AND winner_id=:02))
```

Should be:

```
AND ((type='employer' AND owner_id=:02)
OR (type='employee' AND winner_id=:another02))
```

And then bind to it:

```
$dbStatement->bindParam(':01',$Type);
$dbStatement->bindParam(':02',$UserID);
$dbStatement->bindParam(':another02',$UserID);
$dbStatement->bindParam(':03',$Most);
```

Comment: Sigh ... sometimes php is dumb beyond belief ... anyway thank you for your answer. You are correct!